# Question about a left invariant mean on a group.

Tags: group-theory, functions

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group and let $f:G \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded and continuous function on $G$.

Let $m:L^{\infty}(G) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a left invariant mean on $G$.

Then if there exists some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \leq f$ for all $g \in G$ then we must also have $a \leq m(f)$ since $m\geq 0$ and $m(1_{G})=1$.

It seems that this isn't a very complicated statement, but I can't quite see why it follows. I would appreciate it if someone could explain it for me! Thanks.

Comment: Use the monotonicity of $m$ for $a\cdot 1_G\le f$.

Comment: @Berci but for $g \in G$ we have $f(g) \in \mathbb{R}$ while $(a\cdot 1_{G})(g) \in G$ so does it make sense to say $a\cdot 1_{G} \leq f$?

Comment: Doesn't $1_G$ rather denote the real valued, constant $1$ function here?

Comment: @Berci ah yes, I think i'm just confusing myself